# Chaining string manipulation with multiple patterns and multiple designated replacements

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to change multiple strings in a variable with multiple replacements. Preferably with for example `stringr`because `qdap` has a lot of dependencies and I can't get it to work. I'm inclined to think something like the following should work, but it doesn't. Also not when escaping the string brackets or dots with `\\`.

```
library(stringr)

data <- c("Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.)", 
          "VVD",
          "GROENLINKS", 
          "Democraten 66 (D66)")

str_replace_all(data, c("Partij van de Arbeid (P.v.d.A.)",
                        "GROENLINKS",
                        "Democraten 66 (D66)"),
                c("PVDA", 
                  "GL", 
                  "D66"))
```

Wanted output:

```
> data
[1] "PVDA" "VVD"  "GL"   "D66"
```

Comment: Why can't you make `mgsub` work? What have you tried?

Comment: Ah great! It does now. Had to escape all te dots and brackets thanks!